# Django Models with sub Models dependencies in PostgreSQL database

Tags: python, postgresql, django-models

I am trying to implement some Django model classes to store a variety of different model objects into one entry.

I want to create three objects;

```
Product Object containing: ( String(part number), String(client id))
Side Object containing: (string(name), product(product), array(User(operator)))
Line object containing: Side(A), Side(B), string(name) bool(status)
```

Line object containing Side(A), Side(B), string(name) bool(status)

and store them in my PostgreSQL database so I can view them using

I have written the following code

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User    

class Product(models.Model) :  
    customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    sienna_pn = models.CharField(max_length=22)  
  
class Side(models.Model) :
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    operators = models.ManyToManyField(User)  
  
class Line(models.Model) :  
    line = models.IntegerField()  
    status = models.BooleanField()  
    A = models.ForeignKey(Side, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="Line_A")  
    B = models.ForeignKey(Side, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="Line_B")
```

----Views.py ----
...

```
new_product = Product(customer_name="General", customer_id="0000", sienna_pn="labels")  
new_product.save()
new_product2 = Product(customer_name="General", customer_id="0000", sienna_pn="Carboard")
new_product2.save()
side_1A = Side.objects.create(name="1A", product=new_product)
user = request.user
side_1A.operators.add(user)
side_1A.save()
users = User.objects.all().filter(username="riley")
user2 = users[0]
side_1B = Side.objects.create(name="1B", product=new_product2)
side_1B.operators.add(user2)
side_1B.save()
line_1 = Line.objects.create(name="line1", status=0, A=side_1A, B=side_1B)
```

However, when I implement this I get all users that exist as the operators in Side rather than the ones I add manually. Picture of problem below:
[image: Problem in image form]

Comment: Are you sure the `class Operators` is necessary? It seems to me like that could be a boolean column on `User`

Comment: Without Operators how would I add multiple users to one side? I have tried using the PostgreSQL ArrayField but I was unable to use that with Users referenced by Foreign Key.

Comment: @Daviid I have removed the operators group and updated my problem / Images